# Clear working of $\sin(\arccos(-\frac13))$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Can someone show this please. I always had trouble with this in A Level.

It is strange that this expression as an exact value because there is no exact value of $\arccos(-\frac13)$.

Comment: Draw a triangle and mark on the "arccos($-\frac{1}{3}$)" angle, then what would the sin of it be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: put $\arccos (-{1\over 3})=\alpha$. Then $\cos\alpha =-{1\over 3}$. Can you calculate $\sin \alpha$?

Comment: oh yeah, just square both sides and use identities. thanks

Comment: Well done! @snowman

Comment: you shouldn't congratulate me since I am at uni and I should have known this from the start.